# Does Vishnu's Padma or Lotus flower have a name?

Tags: vishnu

Vishnu is always to be depicted holding the four attributes associated with him, being:

1. A Conch shell or **Shankha**, named "*Panchajanya*", held by the upper left hand, which represents Vishnu's power to create and maintain the universe.
2. The **Chakra**, a sharp-spinning discus-like weapon, named "*Sudarshana*", held by the upper right hand, which symbolises the purified spiritualised mind.
3. A Mace or **Gada**, named "*Kaumodaki*", held by the lower left hand, symbolises Vishnu's divine power is the source all spiritual, mental and physical strength.
4. A Lotus flower or **Padma**, held by the lower right hand, represents spiritual liberation, Divine perfection, purity and the unfolding of Spiritual consciousness within the individual.

Notice that all the above attributes other than *Padma* has a name.

Does Vishnu's Padma or Lotus flower have a name? If not, why not?

Comment: Drutasraba - Padma name Lotus flower or Padma, held by the lower right hand, represents spiritual liberation, Divine perfection, purity and the unfolding of Spiritual consciousness within the individual.

Answer (score 2):

Although not the specific name as you enquired but [**Srimad Bhagavatam**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/11/18) is naming   the lotus of Lord Vishnu which he is holding in his hand  as his   "Leela Kamal" . This lotus is having 6 opulences like  prosperity , Dharma , Laxmi ,  Gyan (knowledge) etc.

> भगवान् भगशब्दार्थ **लीलाकमल**मुद्वहन् |
>  धर्मं यशच्श्र
>   भगवांच्श्रामरव्यजनेSभजत् ||SB 12.11.18||
>
> bhagavān bhaga-śabdārthaṁ **līlā-kamalam** udvahan
>  dharmaṁ yaśaś
>   ca bhagavāṁś cāmara-vyajane ’bhajat
>
> Playfully carrying a lotus, which represents the various opulences
>   designated by the word bhaga, the Supreme Lord accepts service from a
>   pair of cāmara fans, which are religion and fame.

See the  word " Leela Kamal" in the verse. So the Padma in Lord Vishnu's hand can also  be called by this name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The linked verse in Srimad BhAgavatam is explaining the "leela" as an adjective in the sense of "pastime lotus" or "Playfully carrying a lotus" - Would this be correct explanation over it being a proper noun name?

Comment: Yes , i was aware of this fact while writing the answer , so i said that it can also be called , but i think it can also be used as noun. So both the things will be correct , yes of course the word leela  as an adjective is used in the sense of "pastime lotus" or "Playfully carrying a lotus" at the first place.

Comment: leelekamal is not a name. Kalidas has used it in describing lotus in some woman's hand so far as i remember